# AngularJS parameters in UI-router not showing other values

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

I am new to AngularJS and using UI-router. What I want to achieve is how can I access other details on my object arrays on my controller based on the id I've passed on the URL and show it to the view I have made. You can access sample code [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/6OGeQffIUkGfM61lH8il/).

In here, when the user clicked the destination, it will show the list of destinations indicated in my object array (**South Cebu** and **Bataan**) which I already achieved. Please see the [code preview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbSbx.png).

I am having a hard time to achieve when the user clicked one of the destinations displayed, it should show the destination name and the top destination names (**topDesti.name**).

For example, when the user clicked South Cebu, it should show **South Cebu** (destination name) and **Sirao Flower Farm**, **Moalboal**, **Basilica Minore del Santo Niño**, ... etc. (top destination names). And when the user clicked Bataan, it should show **Bataan** (destination name) and **Mount Samat**, **World War II Museum** (top destination names).

NOTE: I am using only **destiArtiController** --- **destiArtiController.js**, please disregard ***destiController.js***

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would want to split your `$scope.details` into separate JSON files and pull those inside `angular.config` with **resolve**.

But for your code to simply work you need to add `<div ui-view></div>` into `desti.html` (outside of ng-repeat).

Then to show a specific destination, change

```
<div ng-repeat="detail in details">
```

to

```
<div ng-if="detail.id == id" ng-repeat="detail in details">
```

in `destiArti.html`

Comment: Thank you @Aleksey Solovey!